# Export Javascript symbols in a library using the Google Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm missing something when it comes to exporting symbols using the Google Closure Compiler. What I want to accomplish is to create a Javascript library and export only those functions that clients can use.

The documentation states to use the @export annotation on those functions and properties that you want to export. But it also states that you must define both goog.exportSymbol and goog.exportProperty with the same method signature in their own codebase. So for example:

```
/** @export */
var DoSomething = (function () {
});

goog.exportSymbol('DoSomething', goog.exportSymbol);
```

I downloaded the closure library and it does contain a base.js file that contains the goog.exportSymbol function.

But how do you include base.js? All examples show it being included within a web page. But I don't want a web page and the compiler works with javascript code and not web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `--generate_exports` flag is used, the compiler adds the appropriate `goog.exportSymbol` or `goog.exportProperty` call for each occurrence of `@export`. This is why the symbols must be included in the compilation.

To include base.js in your compilation, simply pass it to the compiler using the `--js` flag before you pass in your own code. There's nothing magic going on here - it's just a javascript library.